# I2C convert to MRAA-AIO using Sparkfun shield for Edison

Tags: intel-edison

i am trying to write a code using Intel Sample for Grove TP401 GAS Sensor and as hardware also the SparkFun ADC Block which works on I2C. I see that SparkFun Block has a Lib.

Questions:

Do i have to use that Lib in order to use the block/shield?
If yes, can you show me how to change (or tell me what should i do) the sample code to read from the Analog Input (let's say AIN0) from ADC Block?

Any help would be appreciated - sorry for stupid questions, i am a beginner.
Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

I would say best way is to start from [getting started] (https://software.intel.com/en-us/get-started-edison-linux). Once you have setup the board, you can refer to the [code samples] (https://software.intel.com/en-us/iot/hardware/sensors/grove-air-quality-sensor) for sensors to get started with your project.